# Display content of an Array of Objects with Interpolation in Angular2 Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

#### Application

A simple Search bar and a button where user enters a keyword and the response returned is from a RESTful server (HTTP GET requests)

#### `simplesearch.ts`

```
export class SimpleSearch {
    kw: string; // keyword
    resp: string; // response from Server
}
```

#### `simplesearch.service.ts`

Has a simple method called `searchData` which does a HTTP GET request with the user's keyword as a query search. (Code not included for brevity)

#### `simplesearch.component.ts`

```
/*All respective headers and @Component removed from brevity*/
const OUTPUT: SimpleSearch[] = []; // create an array for storing Objects

export class SimpleSearchComponent {
    Output = OUTPUT; // define variable for array
    constructor(private httpServ: SimpleSearchService, private temp: SimpleSearch) {}

/*Search button on HTML file does this*/
Search(inputVal: string) {
    this.temp.kw = inputVal; // store the value of user's input
    this.httpServ.searchData(inputVal)
          .then(res => this.temp.resp = res); // store the response in temp.resp

    // push the Object on the Output Array
    this.Output.push({kw: this.temp.kw, resp: this.temp.resp}); 
    }
}
```

#### Interpolation Variable

I use `Output` as an Interpolation Variable for my HTML template. I show the data in an unordered list

```
<ul>
     <li *ngFor="let keyword of Output">
         <span>{{keyword.kw}}</span>
     </li>
</ul>

 Response:
 <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let answer of Output">
        <span>{{answer.resp}}</span> <!-- WHAT TO DO HERE for Array Index-->
     </li>
 </ul>
```

#### Result

I can see the keywords in a list every time a user inputs new keywords but
the responses in the wrong way

> How do I pass Indexing with the Interpolation? Or am I thinking wrong?

The easy way out was to create two separate `Array<String>` for keywords and responses and this works great since I can use the index to delete the contents on the page too but with an Object in an Array I am confused with the key: value representation and the index of the Array (`OUTPUT`) itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question.. however for this statement: *"How do I pass Indexing with the Interpolation? Or am I thinking wrong?"* You can simply do this: `<li *ngFor="let keyword of Output; i as index"> Index: {{i}}`.

Comment: @developer033 I get a delay of one response in the last list. Can I do something like {{answer[i].resp}} in my loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "last list"? I just can see you iterating the same list 2 times... Also I just found a problem in your code.. you're trying to access `this.temp.resp` outside the *async* function (so it's probably undefined).

Comment: The one under `Response` I start with an empty bullet point and when I query again the older response is displayed not the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies exactly where developer noticed, `this.temp.resp` is **outside** the async function. So when you are pushing items in your `Output` array, it's always pushing the previous search with the new keyword, therefore you are getting the behavior that the `resp` is always "one step behind". You can check this to understand this async behavior: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

So let's look at the code and explain what is happening. I assume you have initialized 'temp' since it isn't throwing an error on first search, where `temp.resp` would be undefined unless `temp` is initialized.

```
this.httpServ.searchData(inputVal)
  // this takes some time to execute, so the code below this is executed before 'this.temp.resp' has received a (new) value.
  .then(res => this.temp.resp = res);

// old value of 'temp.resp' will be pushed, or if it's a first search, empty value will be pushed
this.Output.push({kw: this.temp.kw, resp: this.temp.resp});
```

So how to solve this, would be to move the `this.Output.push(...` line **inside** the callback (`then`), so that the correct values will be pushed to the array.

Also I'd change your model to be an `Interface` instead of `Class`. But as to how to change the function and do the assignment inside the callback, I'd also shorten the code a bit and do:

```
Search(inputVal: string) {
  this.httpServ.searchData(inputVal)
    .then(res => {
       // we are pushing values inside callback now, so we have correct values! 
       // and 'SimpleSearch' stands for the interface
       this.Output.push(<SimpleSearch>{kw: inputVal, resp: res}); 
    });
  }
}
```

This should take care of it that the corresponding keyword will have the corresponding response! :)

PS. Worth noticing here, is that you'd maybe want to display the keyword while we are waiting for the response for that keyword, I ignored it here though and applied the same as you are currently using.